# Is there real solution to prevent autoplay youtube videos in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, youtube

Is there real solution to prevent autoplay youtube videos in chrome ? that switch for autoplay never work and I need all youtube videos dont start by default.

The only solution I found from the similar question and other answers is this extension

[YouTube™ No Buffer - Stop Auto-playing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-no-buffer-stop-au/afgfpcfjdgakemlmlgadojdfnejkpegd?hl=en#:%7E:text=YouTube%E2%84%A2%20No%20Buffer%20%2D%20Stop%20Auto%2Dplaying&text=This%20extension%20stops%20YouTube%20HTML5,tabs%20from%20buffering%20media%20simultaneously.)

All other extensions did not work with me 4-12-2022

Comment: The switch should stick once you're signed in. It won't if you're not signed in, or  incognito.

Comment: I am signed in.

Comment: Then you're blocking cookies or similar. If you want Google to remember your preferences, all you can do is run an ad-blocker & cross-site cookie blocker. As for the rest, they want to know where & when you've been. If you block them, they won't keep your prefs.

Comment: I tried now still play when ad blocker disabled. In Firefox Enhancer for YouTube work fine but not in Chrome

Comment: That switch works for me, and I am never signed in in Youtube.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - mine works until I reboot, though Google does seem to want me to sign in again every few days now. It never used to ask.

Comment: @Tetsujin In my case, it might be because I use Edge and Firefox more than Chrome. However, I have the same extensions in all 3 browsers.